# Big O notation proof statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

So here it is: 
If $f(n) = O(g(n))$ and $d(n) = Ο(h(n))$, then I have to prove the following:
$$f(n) + d(n) = Ο(g(n)+ h(n))$$

Any ideas?

Comment: You haven't included what you have tried so far, so I'd suggest the first step is to use the definition of big-O notation to understand what the initial statement means. Then try to apply this to $f(n)+d(n)$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You know that $\exists k \in \mathbb{N}, c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall n \geq k, f(n) \leq c*g(n)$. Similarly there $\exists k' \in \mathbb{N}, c' \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall n \geq k', d(n) \leq c'*h(n)$. Now notice simply that for all $n \geq \max(k,k')$:

$$
f(n) + d(n) \leq cg(n)+c'h(n) \leq \max(c,c')(g(n)+h(n))\implies f(n)+d(n) = \mathcal{O}(g(n)+h(n))
$$

That was a little terse, so to quickly just elaborate, I get the inequalities from the top by noting that $f(n) = \mathcal{O}(g(n))$ and $d(n) = \mathcal{O}(h(n))$, and then I can use those to see that I satisfy the definition of big oh for $f(n) + d(n)$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. If you want to practice, you can prove similar things using basically the same technique for the multiplicative rule as well. For questions like this, the proof follows typically from definition manipulations =).

Comment: Would the person who downvoted the answer care to explain? If something is unclear / incorrect, it would be better for me to fix it directly.